# Inserting encodeURIComponent() into existing Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I sourced the following code that is successfully extracting ids from the URL into form inputs:

```
function querystring(key) {
   var re=new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)'+key+'=(.*?)(?=&|$)','gi');
   var r=[], m;
   while ((m=re.exec(document.location.search)) != null) r.push(m[1]);
   return r;
 escape;
}

$('#firstname').val(querystring('FirstName'));
$('#lastname').val(querystring('LastName'));
$('#emailaddress').val(querystring('EmailAddress'));
```

However, when the email address is fed into a disabled input, the @ displays as %40 instead. The form submits fine with this discrepancy, however aesthetically it may lead to customers being confused.

I believe I can use encodeURIComponent() to ensure the @ appears correctly in  the input, however I do not know how to insert this into my existing code. I understand the basics of Jquery but am not advanced enough to make this change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I suggest you take some time to fully understand the code you "sourced", using code you don't fully understand is a great way to cause yourself problems in the future. That said, in this case all you really need to understand is the last three lines of jQuery, and the `decodeURIComponent()` function (You want "decode" not "encode")

Answer (score 0):

you must decode URI component by using `decodeURIComponent(key);` 
or you should separate each key from URI and decode separately. I think you should decode your URI first and then pass it into the queryString function.